# Call JavaScript function on a page automatically with Chrome?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

When I load a particular webpage, I'd like to call a Javascript function that exists within their page. I could use a bookmarklet with `javascript:TheFunction();`, but I'd like to know if there's an easier way to do it, either with a Chrome extension or otherwise.

Comment: You could also use the debugger console,though, I think you're looking to automate. A chrome extension would work. See: http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/samples.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With chrome, you can either install a grease monkey script directly or get the [Blank Canvas](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/pipnnjjknlabchljabhmnpdfpdobpnkk) script handler plugin (the latter of which I use).

Comment: Looks like this does most of the heavy lifting for me, thanks!

Comment: Glad to help :) it is really easy to use and a wonderful extension (I use it *all* the time).

Answer (score 1):

Chrome extensions run in a sandbox so you cannot call a function directly from the webpage code how you want. you either have to use javascript:fuction(); and set document.location, or you can create script elements on the page with a callback to your own extension. check out how this guy did it:

https://convore.com/kynetx/kbx-writing-durable-code/

i am refering to this post, and the one above and below it specifically

```
var anewscript = document.createElement("script");
anewscript.type = 'text/javascript';
anewscript.innerHTML=' callback_tmp= function (mydata){ ' +
' document.getElementById("someElement").onclick(mydata);' +
'}';
document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(anewscript);
```

Answer (score -1):

An alternative option is to modify the javascript function to make it globally accessible from the [Chrome] debug console.

Change the function from for example

```
function foo(data)
```

to

```
foo = function(data)
```

then using the debug console, call the method with the attributes required

```
data = {my: "data"}
foo(data)
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with what I wanted, I didn't say anything about a console. I wanted to have some JavaScript code injected and executed when the page loaded in my extension. You're also over 1 year late to this party, and I already accepted the answer.